# How to find out if my mail client software is executing JavaScript or not?

Tags: email, thunderbird, javascript

I read that some mail client software like Thunderbird can execute JavaScript when viewing the HTML-version of an e-mail. I can usually tell from the plain-text version if an e-mail message is spam or not, but I still would like to keep JavaScript away from my e-mails.

I have seen ways to deactivate it on Thunderbird, but in Evolution on Linux I have no idea where to check for that or if the software even supports JavaScript at all.

Now my question is, how can I check that? My idea was to send myself a HTML message with a `<script>` tag that runs the `alert()` function, but I don't see any way to send my own HTML code in Evolution.

---

Update: I managed to send myself an e-mail via the shell of my mailserver following this post on stackoverflow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3317304/5000766

However, I am not sure if writing an e-mail like this is even sufficient enough for a test:

```
[...]
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
[...]

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello, world!</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('test');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `alert` is likely disabled in the mail client.  A better test might be to use JavaScript to modify the body of the email, or use it to ping a server with CORS enabled.